# Nginx disallow download file

Tags: security, nginx

I'm facing an issue with include files in my web app. They are all stored in a `inc/` subdirectory. If I open the browser and point to: `www.mysite.com/inc/` I get a 404 not found which is ok.

If I point to: `www.mysite.com/inc/connection.inc` file that contains db info I can actually download it which is absolutely not good!

I have this configuration in default website config:

```
location ~ /(ajax|inc|prints|temp) {
  deny all;
  return 404;
}
```

How can I avoid files being downloaded?

Answer (score 4):

Found the solution. It was as simple as

```
location ~ \.inc {
  deny all;
}
```

The problem is that there is ONLY 1 thread ion google about this issue.

Answer (score 1):

The `location` block seems to match the URI and should deny access. Therefore, either it is in the wrong server block, it is overridden by some other `location` block, or you failed to restart `nginx`.

On a more general point. If `connection.inc` is not required by the client, then why risk placing it inside the document root?

Comment: Actually right. Didn't think about placing inc/ outside the root.